# Why does "Why did my PC restart?" error occur while installing windows 10 on virtualbox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, installation

I've tried installing windows 10 on VirtualBox for more than 10 times, but the error shown in the link is what comes always (even after switching to bridged adapter and clicking on "next").

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4EcGd06qFo3y00wJECFPv5TZ6ZPSNB7/view

I've tried changing a number of the settings each time I tried to install it.

I'm running a Windows 10 host.

But other VMs like Ubuntu and Debian are working fine. Only the windows 10 guest has this problem...

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Download the ISO from Microsoft official website and install again, see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: I downloaded the media creation tool form microsoft website and the created the iso